# Adding Elements and Attributes in XQuery

Tags: xquery

Using the code from [this W3Schools sample](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_add.asp):

```
<html>
    <body>

        <h1>Bookstore</h1>

        <ul>
        {
           for $x in doc("books.xml")/bookstore/book
           order by $x/title
           return <li>{data($x/title)}. Category: {data($x/@category)}</li>
        }
        </ul>

    </body>
</html>
```

I saved it to test.html & opened it in a browser. All I see is the code rather than the result.

I am obviously missing something; how do I see the results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend getting an XQuery processor such as [Saxon](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/#F9.3HE). You can use this along with the `books.xml` sample and the XQuery sample to produce an HTML file to view in the browser. (Saxon-HE is free and is an excellent (the best?) processor.)

For XQuery directly in a browser (IE only for now I think), take a look at [XQIB – XQuery In the Browser](http://www.xqib.org/).

I would definitely stick with Saxon while you're just learning XQuery. What would be perfect to help you write/test XQuery while you learn it is [oXygen Editor](http://www.oxygenxml.com/). They have different pricing options and is worth every dime.

Comment: Thank you; your response has clarified a lot for me.

Answer (score 0):

[Kernow](http://kernowforsaxon.sourceforge.net/) works well. Copy your XML document into the Kernow root folder and execute your queries in the "XQuery Sandbox".